# Unable to connect to Oracle 12C using Spring Boot 2.7.3, Java 11 and cwallet.sso

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, ojdbc

I've created a small spring boot CommandLineRunner app to connect to an Oracle 12c database over SSL.
I know the SSL is set up correctly as I can connect to the Oracle source using a SSL Connection in AWS DMS.

I have the following dependencies in my pom.xml file:

```
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
           <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
           <version>19.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>oraclepki</artifactId>
            <version>19.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.oracle.database.security</groupId>
           <artifactId>osdt_cert</artifactId>
           <version>19.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
           <artifactId>osdt_core</artifactId>
           <version>19.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

And here is a snippet from my app:

```
            Security.addProvider(new oracle.security.pki.OraclePKIProvider());

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(retry_count=5)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)" + 
                    "(port=2484)(host=redacted.com))(connect_data=(service_name=REDACTED.COM))" + 
                    "(security=(ssl_server_cert_dn=\"CN=redacted.com,OU=redacted,O=redacted,C=uk\")))";
            
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            
            properties.put("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:/oracle/network/admin/cwallet.sso");
            properties.put("oracle.net.wallet_location","file:///C:/oracle/network/admin/cwallet.sso");
            properties.put("oracle.net.ssl_version","1.2");
            properties.put("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType","SSO");
            properties.put("oracle.net.ssl_server_dn_match", "true");   
            properties.put("oracle.net.ssl_cipher_suites","(SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA)");
            properties.put("oracle.net.ssl_client_authentication","false");
            
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,properties);
```

Currently I'm running the app locally on my Windows Laptop.

Does anyone have a working Spring Boot example of connecting to Oracle using just a cwallet.sso file

When the app tries to establish the connection it throws the following:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:854)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:793)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:57)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:747)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:562)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189)
    at com.electrocomponents.application.Application.initialise(Application.java:64)
    at com.electrocomponents.application.Application.run(Application.java:34)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:755)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at com.electrocomponents.application.Application.main(Application.java:27)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:571)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:548)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:682)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:309)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1596)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:588)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection timed out: connect, socket connect lapse 21039 ms. redacted.com/17.256.95.22 2484 0 1
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpsNTAdapter.connect(TcpsNTAdapter.java:295)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:174)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:510)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:482)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:474)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:694)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:194)
    at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.connect(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:99)
    at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.<init>(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:85)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpsNTAdapter.connect(TcpsNTAdapter.java:229)
    ... 21 more
```

I have read this Oracle document [SSL With Oracle JDBC Thin Driver](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl-130128.pdf) but this was written in 2010.

I logged onto the Oracle server and viewed the User and Trusted Certificates using the following command:

orapki wallet display -wallet cwallet.sso

In the JDBC Url, I matched the ssl_server_cert_dsn to the output from the above orapki command.

I have the following in my sqlnet.ora file (in the same directory as the cwallet.sso)

```
WALLET_LOCATION = (SOURCE = (METHOD = file) (METHOD_DATA = (DIRECTORY = "C:\\oracle\\network\\admin")))
SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH = yes
sqlnet.wallet_override = true
```

And this in my tnsnames.ora file (in the same directory as the cwallet.sso)

```
database_high=
   (description=
      (address=
         (protocol=tcps)
         (port=2484)
         (host=redacted.com)
      )
      (connect_data=
         (service_name=REDACTED.COM)
      )
      (security=
          (ssl_server_cert_dn="CN=redacted.com,OU=redacted,O=redacted,C=uk")
      )
   )
```

I am expecting the connection to establish

Comment: Any specific reason to use wallet instead of JKS?

Comment: Are you using Autonomous Database? or Are you connecting to on-premise database? You are adding too many connection properties. If you are connecting to ADB, it is quite straight forward (https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/getting-started-using-jdbc.html)

Comment: Hi, we're trying to connect to an on-prem database